# what does this "His expression brightens at the treat" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Can anyone tell me what the following means?

> His expression brightens at the treat.

Answer (score 3):

It is synonymous with the following:

> He [smiles/becomes happier] when he looks at the treat

> **brighten**
>   to start looking or feeling happier
>   *She frowned anxiously, then suddenly her face brightened.*

([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brighten))